# Google storage bucket not visible in google chrome

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Unable to see the buckets in google storage of google cloud platform in chrome browser but its visible in internet explorer browser since today.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I was using outdated version of chrome. I upgraded chrome and now works perfectly fine.